# Issue building a function using Lavaan syntax

Tags: r, function, syntax, r-lavaan

I am trying to write a very simple function for my use of lavaan in order to obtain an effect from a very simple model. The code is below:

```
library(lavaan)
states <- as.data.frame(state.x77)

Effect<-function(dataset, X1, Y)
{
Model<-'
X1 ~~ X1; Y ~~Y;
Y ~ X1;'
fit<-lavaan(Model, dataset)
return(summary(fit))
}
```

When I call Effect(states, Murder, Income) or Effect(states, "Murder", "Income"), the following message displays:

"Error in lavaan(Model, dataset) :
lavaan ERROR: missing observed variables in dataset: Y X1"

Everything is fine when I write the following though:

```
Model<-'
Murder ~~ Murder; Income ~~ Income;
Income ~ Murder;'
fit<-lavaan(Model, states)
summary(fit)
```

My guess is that lavaan() in my Effect function may indeed use the dataset "states", but that it is not equating X1 and Y with Murder and Income. Would someone have a clue on how I could solve this?

Many thanks,

Comment: Can you include a sample of what the state.x77 dataframe looks like? Your code is not reproducible without that data. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

The problem is, that the variables `Y` and `X1` indeed are not part of the `state.x77` data. The most straight forward way to do that would be to let the Effect function paste the model syntax using `X1` and `Y` as character arguments; for example

```
data(state, package = "datasets")
states <- as.data.frame(state.x77)

Effect<-function(dataset, X1, Y)
{
  Model<-
  paste0(X1, "~~", X1, ";\n",
         Y, "~~", Y, ";\n",
         Y, "~~", X1, ";")  
  fit<-lavaan::lavaan(Model, dataset)
  return(lavaan::summary(fit))
}
```

Now `Effect(states, X1 = "Murder", Y = "Income")` should provide the desired results.